# Count rows for multiple tables in SQL db and storing the results in a log table with timestamp on weekly basis

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a log table that keeps a tab of row count of multiple tables. The data in these table refreshes on a weekly basis. So, I am looking to record the row count increase per refresh.

Comment: I have *assumed* SQL Server here, however, if you are using a different product that you can use SSMS with (such as Azure SQL Database) please [edit] your post to correct the tag(s).

Comment: This question doesn't contain a question, just a number of requirements for a process you are trying to build. If you get stuck with a particular part of this work and have a specific question about code you are writing and struggling with, that would make a good question for stackoverflow.